# Insert on python list on a particular offset

Tags: python

I'm having a python list preinitialized like this:
eventarray=[None]*10000

Is there any other way to preinitialize this list,so that 10000 can be a variable to be changed from different functions inside,without changing the data in the list.

Note:preinitialisation is done for inserting value on a particular offset of list.

Comment: What do you mean "without changing the data in the list"? Why not just set n=10000 and then eventarray=[None]*n ?

Comment: The title "Insert on python list at a particular offset" suggests you want `list.insert()`. But the actual text doesn't appear to be asking anything like that (and I'm not sure what it is asking).

Comment: this list is having a global scope,if i change n from other function it's not updating the eventarray size.

Comment: iguananau, preinitialization is done for inserting on a particular offset.

Comment: @Vibing what do you mean by `inserting on a particular offset`?

Comment: Maybe you want to extend the list preserving the remaining items?
eventarray.extend([None] * n)

Comment: matt,i mean inserting on particular index and preserving that values

Comment: faruk,prbably i'm gng to try ths...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can infer from your question, you want to create a list with global scope, with its length determined at runtime.

Edit: The following code now extends the list as necessary each time my_list_creator is accessed:

```
foo = []

def my_list_creator(n):
    '''Makes the nth value in a list n. If the list is not
    long enough, it extends it, initialised with None.
    '''
    global foo

    if len(foo) < n:
        foo.extend([None] * (n - len(foo)))

    foo[n-1] = n

def access_a_global():
    print foo

def another_func():
    my_list_creator(10)
    access_a_global()
    my_list_creator(20)        
    access_a_global()

another_func()
```

`foo` is global in scope, but is initialised as necessary.

Comment: glgl,when i call my_list_creator() for the second time with a different size, the values in all the indexes are replaced by None,this shoulnot happen

Comment: @Vibing of course, that's the nature of a variable with global scope. What do you actually _want_ to happen?

Comment: @Vibing I've modified the answer so it increases the length of the list as necessary, without completely reinitialising the list.

Comment: Henry foo[n-1] = n,wht tis step fr?

Comment: Oh nothing, that just makes the initialisation a bit more interesting (it sets some value to be n). Replace it with whatever initialisation you want.

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to tell exactly what you are asking, so this might not be what you want. If it is not, you should clarify your question.

To create a list of `n` elements where every element is `None`, you can do this:

```
myList = [None]*n
```

`n` must be in scope to do this, and future changes to `n` will not effect the list length.

If you want to insert a value into a list, and shift the rest of the values right, you can use [`list.insert(i,x)`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html):

```
myList = [None]*10000
myList.insert(5,0)
```

This will insert a `0` at index 5, and will shift the remaining values (indices 5 and higher) to the right one. This results in a list who's length is one more than before the insert. If you just want to set a value in your list:

```
myList = [None]*10000
myList[5] = 0
```

This will result in a list of 10,000 elements with the 6th element (index of 5) being 0. The length of the initial and final lists will be the same.